# Problems installing packages

Tags: install.packages

I have problems to install packages and I am not sure where the problem lays.
I tries to install, gives a lot of warnings and when I try to get to the library it is not there

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/ts/xt7r92890wndz4_d5y2t27znb7q8z1/T/RtmpNAOKoW/downloaded_packages’

> library (tidyverse)
>   Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’

Comment: What exactly are you installing?

Comment: I am trying to install tidyverse package in this case, but I am obtaining the same error message with all packages I am installing...